# Android any class or object to hold any type of widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to create new object which can hold any type of widgets basically which we can use in form like `Spinner`, `EditText`, `CheckBox`, `RadioButton`.

My goal is to build validation library and I am try to focus as above widget it have one common method `requestFocus` but I do not know how to hold any type of Object in during init.

For example I have used

```
public class validationCollection{
 public int ValidationType;
 public String val;
 public String FieldName; // Will help to display appropriate message
 //I need to hold one widget object over here so I can make focus on it once validation return error it should focus on particular element 

}
```

Please please please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do all widgets not inherit from a base widget class? Can you not define the variable as the base class and thereby store and child of that class?

Answer (score 0):

`View` is the base class for Android UI widgets.

If you look at the [JavaDoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), you can see that it lists "Known Direct Subclasses" and "Known Indirect Subclasses", which makes it easy to see what extends it.

Similarly, if you click into a subclass, you can see the object inheritance hierarchy:

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.view.View
       ↳    android.widget.TextView
```